# Survival Analysis - Early vs Later Mortality

Tags: survival

I was wondering if, in survival analysis, is there any statistical approach/procedure that can help us identifying effects on early or/and later mortalities (meaning if a certain treatment is associated with more early mortalities than the controls, for example).

An example dataset could be the `lung` dataset from the `survival` package.

```
head(lung)
  inst time status age sex ph.ecog ph.karno pat.karno meal.cal wt.loss
1    3  306      2  74   1       1       90       100     1175      NA
2    3  455      2  68   1       0       90        90     1225      15
3    3 1010      1  56   1       0       90        90       NA      15
4    5  210      2  57   1       1       90        60     1150      11
5    1  883      2  60   1       0      100        90       NA       0
6   12 1022      1  74   1       1       50        80      513       0
```

What I am asking if there is any way to, for example, link `age` to earlier mortality levels (`time` to change `status`).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You have to be very specific in what you mean by "Early vs Later Mortality." Are you interested in the probability of dying *during* certain periods of time (early versus late), or an early-versus-late difference in the *hazard* of dying (given that someone has already survived until a certain time)?

Say that you have 2 treatment groups of the same initial size, with one very effective treatment `A` and one very ineffective treatment `B`. Those in the treatment `B` group will have more early deaths and fewer late deaths than those in the treatment `A` group.

Nevertheless, the *relative hazard* of death between the 2 groups--the probabilities of dying given that one has already survived to a given point in time--might be constant over time. You have fewer deaths at late times in the treatment `B` group simply because fewer in that group survive to late times. That's what's assumed in a standard proportional hazards model, in which `age` at treatment might be used to evaluate overall survival on its own or (in an interaction term) how the effect of a treatment might differ depending on `age`.

Alternatively, the treatments might have big differences in terms of the *hazard* of death at early times but not at later times. For example, those in the treatment `B` group might have a higher hazard of death over the first 2 years, but those in that group lucky enough to survive beyond that have no higher risk of death than those in the treatment `A` group who survived at least 2 years. That can be handled, for example, with time-varying coefficients in a Cox proportional hazards model. The [time dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) of the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) shows some ways to model time-varying hazards.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking into the first scenario, where I am watching if group `A` has higher hazard of death at earlier time than group `B`. I will check your suggestion, thank you!